# Sobre la libreria DataTables

Tags: datatable

Tengo la siguiente cuestión: estoy usando la librería datatables, para que me muestre en formato móvil, la segunda y tercera columna como despegable y no haga  un colapso automaticamente empezando por la ultima columna, es decir quiero que quede como veis en la imagen pero en vez de la descripción que se visualize opciones con los botones y cuando haga un click sobre nombre pues se me despliegue tanto la descripcion como los jugadores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "type": "column"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' />



<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap dtr-inline collapsed" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:grey;">
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes controlar en que orden se ocultan las columnas con la opcion [columns.responsivePriority](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority).

En tu caso quieres mantener la primera y última columna así que usamos `columnDefs`  para identificarlas, también podrías usar simplemente `columns` y dar una prioridad a cada columna según tus necesidades:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "type": "column",
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
      { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' />



<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap dtr-inline collapsed" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:grey;">
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Jugadores</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miguel</td>
      <td>Jugador de futbol</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <button>Borrar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias, lo he probado y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido, en ese caso deberías marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros que tengan la misma duda vean que está resuelta